# How to add key to label when label has value exactly same to key ? ....PHP

Tags: php, logic

User gives a input for label and for key too with the other parameters(Key and Label are just example)
I want to add Key to label only once means only at first execution (first button press - but after that on every button click it should not add; php file loads on every button)after that it should be avoided to add (prepend) (key_valuelabel_value)
So my existing code adds key to label but this fails when if user gives label  which has value similar to key.

For example:- `key='123' and label='123 test' then my condition fails`.

So anyone suggest me on this how can I handle this case ?

This is php, everytime it reloads so counter also failed.

Comment: your question does not make any sense, please edit it

Comment: `but this fails when if user gives label which has value similar to key` - as I see, you can add different values any times, but only unique? i.e. we will have something like that:  label = '123 456 789 test' ?

Comment: yes for this example, it also fails because label already starts with key value(123). Initially it continusly adds the key value to label but after that error i added conditions to handle that like if label doesn't contain label - add, contains at last or in middle - add (using strpos) but when label already has value at start similar to key then it fails. That's why asked for any suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't asking why do you need that. Hope this code can helps:

```
function isKeyInLabel($key, $label) {
    $keys = explode(' ', $label);

    // remove last element (it's a label)
    array_pop($keys);

    return in_array($key, $keys);
 }
```

usage example:

```
 // this condition will returns true
 if (isKeyInLabel('456', '123 456 789 test')) {
    // already exists
 }
```

*notice: of course you can't use keys or labels with spaces*

UPD:
You'll need another variable, for example:

```
// of course you need a place where you can save this array
// as possible place you can use session or cookies, or
// whatever you want, here is session usage example
session_start();

// this hash will have keys that already executed
$execKeys = isset($_SESSION['execKeys'])?$_SESSION['execKeys']:array();

// assuming that $execKeys[$label] is an array
if (isset($execKeys[$label]) && in_array($key, $execKeys[$label])) {
  // code already executed
} else {
    $execKeys[$label] = isset($execKeys[$label])?$execKeys[$label]:array();
    $execKeys[$label][] = $key;
    // and if you still need it
    $label = $key.' '.$label;
}

$_SESSION['execKeys'] = $execKeys;
```

Comment: This just give me the Key value present in Label value or not. but i want, code should know that if it is first execution then key should be added in Label fiels else not. When i press button the php file loads every time that's why only on first click Key Value should be added to label value.

Comment: mmm... if the key is not present in the label, it means first execution, as I suppose, then you should add key in the label, next time when you'll analyze the label its value should be '$key label', ofc this will be not the first execution.. am I right ?

Comment: yes you are right, i know this is one case but i'm talking about when $label already comprises of $key then it is the first execution then it should add to $label; but how the code knows that it is the first execution. That's what i am asking

Comment: If `$label` already includes a `$key`, the code can't detect first execution (of that `$key`) using current method of detection, without additional variables.